# Tunnelblick on macOS - failed to load - (libkern/kext)

Tags: macos, vpn, kernel-extensions

I get the following error message when I try to connect to my VPN server:

```
openvpnstart log:
     Loading tap-notarized.kext
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-notarized.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) system policy prevents loading; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-notarized.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) system policy prevents loading; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-notarized.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) system policy prevents loading; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-notarized.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) system policy prevents loading; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-notarized.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) system policy prevents loading; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     Unable to load net.tunnelblick.tun and/or net.tunnelblick.tap kexts in 5 tries. Status = 27
```

The following command

```
kextstat | grep -v com.apple
```

prints

```
  120    0 0xffffff7f83eff000 0x8000     0x8000     com.sophos.driver.devctrl (9.9.4) 80C0508D-B31F-3069-BA35-7CE532860385 <22 6 5 3 1>
  189    0 0xffffff7f859a6000 0x7000     0x7000     com.sophos.nke.swi (9.9.4) FE4EB493-673F-372C-81AD-27AD0BC83BF6 <5 1>
  190    0 0xffffff7f859ad000 0x8000     0x8000     com.sophos.kext.oas (9.9.4) 7CED455E-0A13-323E-B39B-FAE664394522 <6 5 2 1>
```

I tried to unload these kext, but without success. I can't uninstall Sophos, because I am not administrator. Do you have any idea how to connect to my VPN server?

Comment: Which version of Macos you are using and what is the version of TunnelBlick on your side ?

Comment: macOS: 10.15.2 (19C57)
Tunnelblick: 3.8.1 (build 5400)